# Angular 2: Updating observable array not displaying

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable

I have a `service` for a client's check_ins and a `get` function that returns the observable.

```
constructor(private clientService: ClientService) {
  this._check_ins = <BehaviorSubject<any>>new BehaviorSubject([]);
}

get check_ins() {
  return this._check_ins
}

updateCheckIns(check_ins) {
  this._check_ins.next(check_ins)
}
```

in my view I subscribe to the check_ins like so:

```
this.check_in_obs = this.checkInService.check_ins.subscribe(check_ins => {
      this.check_ins = check_ins
})
```

and check_in is the parent for another model, repositioning.  When I delete the repositioning, I set it to `null` and attempt to update the check_in to show the repositioning is null:

```
this.check_in.repositioning = null
this.checkInService.updateCheckIns(this.check_ins)
```

This seems to work, and when I print the new value for `this.check_ins`, it is correct, however the view is not updated.  I don't understand why the views value for `this.check_ins` is not in sync with the real value.

Here's the template code:

```
<ion-row class="" id="weigh-in-table" style="flex-wrap:nowrap;overflow-x: scroll;margin-left: 200px;margin-top:21px;">
  <ion-col
    no-padding
    style="min-width:300px;"
    *ngFor="let check_in of check_ins; let i = index"
  >
    <weigh
      [isDraggable]="dragEnabled"
      [check_in]="check_in"
      [check_ins] = "check_ins"
      [client_id]="client.id"
      [current_user]="current_user"
      [program_id]="program_id"
      [client]="client"
      [index]="i"
      [token]="current_user.auth_token"
      >
    </weigh>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: Could you please add your relevant template code as well?

Comment: I've updated the code

Comment: This `get check_ins` method isn't returning an observable, which may be preventing your `subscription` to it in your component from receiving the current value.

Comment: nope.. I don't get any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try and modify your code to accommodate these changes and see if (it makes sense and if) it is working.

> service

```
get check_ins() {
  return this._check_ins.asObservable();
}
```

> component

```
this.check_ins = this.checkInService.check_ins;

// change this to
// this.check_in.repositioning = null
// this.checkInService.updateCheckIns(this.check_ins)
this.checkInService.updateCheckIns(null);
// if you still wanna make use of a this.check_in object please show what you do with it
```

> template

```
<ion-row class="" id="weigh-in-table" style="flex-wrap:nowrap;overflow-x: scroll;margin-left: 200px;margin-top:21px;">
  <ion-col
    no-padding
    style="min-width:300px;"
    *ngFor="let check_in of check_ins | async; let i = index"
  >
    <weigh
      [isDraggable]="dragEnabled"
      [check_in]="check_in"
      [check_ins] = "check_ins | async"
      [client_id]="client.id"
      [current_user]="current_user"
      [program_id]="program_id"
      [client]="client"
      [index]="i"
      [token]="current_user.auth_token"
      >
    </weigh>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Let me know if it made any difference.

Comment: I'm going to accept it as it gets most of the way there.  Pointing out that I had been returning `this._check_ins` rather than `this._check_ins.asObservable();` made a difference.

Comment: Cool, thanks for pointing that out. I was trying to force the object initialized as of type  `BehaviourSubject` (which can be both an observer and an observable) to act as an observable by doing so. Was trying to figure out by mind than actually test it out, lol.